# Chromebook no longer connects to Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, chromebook

A few months ago I picked up a Samsung chromebook from a pawnshop for cheap and I just use it for things most people use a tablet for. Most of the time its just plugged in to my speakers in the basement so I can listen to music whenever I'm down there.

Anyways its worked fine up until about last week, when one night it could no longer connect to my wifi network. I passed it off as just a wifi issue and thought nothing of it. Trying again in the subsequent days it still would not work, claiming that my network is out of range(its not, as I've placed it next to the wireless modem to the same result). When I try to connect to my network it seems to be working fine but the chromebook seems to keep losing and regaining connections for example when I go to connect to a network it'll show other networks in my neighbourhood and mine but the list constantly changes almost as if I took it out of range and back in.

Anyways I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar issue with Samsung chromebooks, or chromeOS in general. I'll post the product name/number of my chromebook later, as I'm not at home currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your best bet would be to restore your chromebook and if that resolves the issue. If not, crack it open and check if the antennas disconnected from the wifi card.

How to restore: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en

Comment: The wificard had a loose connection on the inside works now.

Answer (score 1):

My Acer C720 suddenly decided my in-room router was 'out of range', after two years of operation. My phone and tablet connect without problem. The Chromebook can see every neighbor's wifi, just not mine. Running Wifi Analyzer shows no other wifis on the same channel. My wifi signal is -59dB, 1000 times stronger than the next strongest (on a different channel).

None of the methods suggested on many web pages worked. Particularly unhelpful is the many guessers calling to 'restart your router' when your other devices are connecting flawlessly.

After two connectionless weeks going through every conceivable option, what finally worked for me was to do a real shutdown:

1. Open a terminal, Ctrl-Alt-T
2. Type: shell
3. Type: sudo shutdown -h now

Note that I run develepor style; not sure if ordinary users can start the shell.

Probably removing the battery would have the same effect. On a C720 that would entail taking the back off.

Answer (score 0):

### Another possibility: the device's MAC isn't allowed by the router

This is probably not the issue for those devices that have been working and suddenly stop connecting, but I'm going to include it here for the benefit of anyone who might be searching for how to troubleshoot 'out of range' messages on a new device.  I just bought my dad a Chromebook and tried to set it up.  The icons for our 2.4 and 5 GHz bands were showing nearly full signal strength at 20 feet distance through four layers of drywall, but trying to sign in to either one resulted in 'Out of Range'.  The reason turned out to be I had set up the MAC whitelist in order to control my nephew's access to the internet over the holidays, but then forgot about it when trying to get the Chromebook set up.